# Bundle product - how to display simple product attributes on list.phtml and view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, bundled-product, product-page

In M1.9.3, we use **bundle products** with 1 combination of 2 simple products to create products. 
How can I display simple product's custom attributes on `list.phtml` and `view.phtml` for the bundle products?